# How to get matching pairs of columns in SQL

Tags: sql, join

I'm not a SQL expert but say I have a table

```
ID    Col A   Col B
id    a1      b1
id1   a2      b2
id2   a3      b3
id3   a4      b4
id4   a1      b5
```

I  want to get  the ID of all rows which match certain pairs of columns. For example I want rows matching (a1, b1) and (a3, b3) which should return id, id3.

Doing this in linq 2 SQL would be simple using a for loop and some sort of key-value pair collection. 
However here's the SQL I have so far

```
    Select * from [MyTable]  WHERE (ColA in ('a1','a3') AND  ColB in ('b1','b3'))
```

this will return a larger subset than I require, specifically it will include non-exact pair matches like row 5 (id4).

I know this requires some sort of self join but I need a bit of help here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried splitting it out into explicit comparisons:

```
SELECT *
  FROM [MyTable]
 WHERE (ColA = 'a1' AND ColB = 'b1')
    OR (ColA = 'a3' AND ColB = 'b3')
```

Comment: I think this is the simplest approach, just means I'll have as many explicit comparisons as I have rows of input data. But it works. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Splitting like GamerJosh is probably the easiest way to do it. Another way would be to build a table in a subquery that has your values in it:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6ca02/4/0

**Query 1**:

```
select t.*
from t
inner join (
  select 'a1' as cola, 'b1' as colb
  union
  select 'a3','b3'
) vals on vals.cola=t.cola and vals.colb=t.colb
```

**[Results]**:

```
|  ID | COLA | COLB |
|-----|------|------|
|  id |   a1 |   b1 |
| id2 |   a3 |   b3 |
```

Also, depending on what database you're using, you could put that subquery in a common table expression at the beginning of the query.

If you're using Oracle, you could do something like

```
select * from mytable where (cola,colb) in (('a1','b1'),('a3','b3'))
```